# Python regex numbers and underscores

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get a list of files from a directory whose file names follow this pattern:

```
PREFIX_YYYY_MM_DD.dat
```

For example

```
FOO_2016_03_23.dat
```

Can't seem to get the right regex.  I've tried the following:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2}).dat')
>>> []

pattern = re.compile(r'*(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2}).dat')
>>> sre_constants.error: nothing to repeat
```

Regex is certainly a weakpoint for me.  Can anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

To get the files, I'm doing:

```
files = [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if pattern.match(f)]
```

PS, how would I allow for .dat and .DAT (case insensitive file extension)?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "escape" it?

Comment: Try `re.compile(r'(?i)\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}\.dat$')` and then `if pattern.search(f)`

Comment: Changing to search did fix my solution when I added the escape character, thanks

Comment: I thought you need to match "date"+`.dat` at the end of the string, that is why I suggested `$` at the end. `(?i)` = `re.I`.

Comment: Your attempts fail because

 1. You compiled an almost correct `(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2}).dat` regex (failed to escape the `.`), but ran with `re.match` (only searches at the string start)
 2. `r'*(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2}).dat'` regex contains an error, as you placed `*` quantifier (*zero or more occurrences, as many as possible*) at the beginning, but you cannot have more than one beginnings so it is considered a human error.

What you need is to *check if the pattern appears at the end of the string*, and *make sure you are using `re.search`*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two issues with your expression:
`re.compile(r'(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2}).dat')`

The first one, as a previous comment stated, is that the `.` right before `dat` should be escaped by putting a backslash (`\`) before. Otherwise, python will treat it as a special character, because in regex `.` represents "any character".

Besides that, you're not handling uppercase exceptions on your expression. You should make a group for this with `dat` and `DAT` as possible choices.

With both changes made, it should look like:

`re.compile(r'(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})\.(?:dat|DAT)')`

As an extra note, I added `?:` at the beginning of the group so the regex matcher ignores it at the results.

Comment: Thanks.  Can you clarify "regex matcher ignores it at the results"?

Comment: @AdamHughes: Ignore this explanation :) That is just a non-capturing group, a construct used for grouping without storing the value in the group buffer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pattern.search()` instead of `pattern.match()`.

`pattern.match()` always matches from the start of the string (which includes the PREFIX).
`pattern.search()` searches anywhere within the string.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = r'\A[a-z]+_\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}\.dat\Z'
>>> string = 'FOO_2016_03_23.dat'
>>> re.search(pattern, string, re.IGNORECASE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 18), match='FOO_2016_03_23.dat'>
>>>
```

It appears to match the format of the string you gave as an example.

Comment: Yes, this works thanks.  Will try to digest it.  What's \Z?

Comment: If you are trying to understand what it does, run the following: `re.compile(pattern, re.DEBUG)`

Comment: Although it doesn't match my .DAT files.  I do have capital .DAT  I am using your original form \[Dd]\[Aa] ....  To be exact:     pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{4})_(\d{2})_(\d{2})\.[Dd][Aa][Tt]')

Comment: That is why you need to call `re.search` with the third parameter `re.IGNORECASE`.

Comment: So what is the \Z for ?

Comment: `\Z` is the unambiguous *very* end of the string.

Comment: Did you run `re.compile(pattern, re.DEBUG)`? If you are in the interpreter, you will see an explanation of what the regular expression means. In particular, it is read as `AT_END_STRING`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should match for what you requested.

```
[^_]+[_]\d{4}[_]\d{2}[_]\d{2}[\.]\w+
```

I recommend using https://regex101.com/ (for python regular expressions) or http://regexr.com/ (for javascript regular expressions) in the future if you want to validate your regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for this resource.

Comment: @AdamHughes: Do not use regexr since it only supports JavaScript regex flavor. Use regex101.com, debuggex.com, and many others that support Python `re`.